# How to check if record is existing in ms access database using vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, where-clause, multiple-records

I have to publish vacant positions in publication system. But before saving in database it will check the Position title in "Postit" column/field and item number in "itemno" column/field if the text already existing in record in the same row. I dont know if it is correct to put many "WHERE" inside the .Open clause or can I put "AND" to avoid many "WHERE".  Can you please help me solve this. Thanks... Some part of the codes is stated below:

Error in this line of code:

```
.Open("Select * from pop where vacantnotvacant ='" & "vacant" & "' , where Position = '" & ListViewEx1.Items.Item(h).SubItems(2).Text & "'", psipopcon, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in place of your open line

```
.Open("Select * from pop where vacantnotvacant ='" & "vacant" & "' and Position = '" & ListViewEx1.Items.Item(h).SubItems(2).Text & "'", psipopcon, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Craig T. Now it's working. Thumbs up! I hope that you can help me on my future questions.